# How to bake a fluid animation with Blender 4?

Tags: fluid-simulation

how do you bake a fluid animation? I have the "domain" object, the fluid and the effector, I changed the number of frames, but with the last version of blender, there is no "bake" button. When I try to render or bake in the "render" category, it shows the cube as an object, and not as a domain (the cube should be invisible).

Thanks

Comment: @Crantisz yes thank you!